# Temerature conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit that displays conversion from a given start to end temp

Tags: python

My instructor wants us to write a program that asks a user for two inputs. A Celsius start temperature and a Celsius end temperature. Then the program is supposed to take those two numbers and convert them into Fahrenheit but it is supposed to list every temperature along the way until it gets to the end temp. So say user inputs 100 as start and 0 as end. The display should show 100 C - 212 F and then decrease displaying all the temps from c to f until 0 c - 32 f. I'm assuming we only use what we've read so far and I'm confused because I've not read anything for calculations or even two user inputs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go.
A function to convert.
Read in inputs seperatly.
if statement, to make the list iterate up or down as needed.

```
def c_to_f(c):
    return 9/5*c + 32

c_start = int(input("Cstart?"))
c_end = int(input("C end?"))

step = 1 if c_start <= c_end else -1

for c in range(c_start, c_end +1,step):
    print(c_to_f(c))
```

Comment: Ok, that works. Thank you. So now if I want it to display the Celsius along side the Fahrenheit is it just add it in the print command? Also I don't think we've started using def yet. Is that to define or definition?

Comment: I have another question please. What is the c for in def c_to_f(c): and print(c_to_f(c))? The Celsius to Fahrenheit I get but the last c in parentheses I'm not sure about. I'm asking because I'm trying to understand what you wrote and trying to make the out put display the Fahrenheit too. I tried to write my own def f_to_c but I didn't understand the (c) and when I wrote return f - 32 5/9 I got invalid syntax.

Comment: the def c_to_f is what we call a  function . It takes a parameter , here called "c" that is what is used inside function to calculate a result.   So we can calculate any conversion by sending in different numbers .   c_to_f(10) , c_to_f(20) etc

Comment: if you found my solution useful, please upvote and except :-)